# XMLHttpRequest open cause chrome on mac to change the page url

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

When I use XMLHttpRequest.open with chrome on a mac. the page address bar changes to the url I am trying to call as a AJAX call. It happens when we do NTML auth and the username and password window pops up. does not do this on a windows computer.

it is like the page is getting redirected to the url that I am passing in the XMLHttpRequest request.

Can someone tell me what is going on here?

P.S. a little more info. this is using CORS. the address bars url changes when we the username and password shows up. after you enter the user name and password the pages just hangs.

On Safari the same thing happens but the page does not hang. it goes on to the site.

This was working in Chrome. But something seems to have changed.

I dont get why a XMLHttpRequest would change the address in the address bar.

Please help

Comment: Same thing happening to me, only on windows machines and only when using chrome. Firefox and Internet explorer behave correctly! Did you find a solution?